# dompdf table margin does not work properly

Tags: php, css, margin, dompdf

I'm creating a PDF file using dompdf. Everything works fine but the margin for tables. I've created a class in css for margin:

```
.margin { margin-left: 2.5cm; margin-right: 2.5cm; }
```

This works fine for every other elements but it does not add the intended margin for the table.

I've tried converting `cm` to `mm` and `px` but the problem was still there!

I've also tried inline styling, it didn't work either.

[image: dompdf table margin not working properly]

The margin set for texts and tables are the same but the result is different.

```
$dompdf->setPaper( 'A4' );
$dompdf->loadHTML( $text );
$dompdf->render();
ob_end_clean();
$dompdf->stream( 'output.pdf' );
```